# Angular2 - Resolve on component selector

Tags: angular

Is there any way to resolve (pre-fetch) data before rendering an component selector?

I would like to pre fetch data before rendering the root component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resolve in your router to prefetch data before going to loading a component with the router

```
path: myPath,
component: components.myComponent,
resolve: {
    data: resolvers.service
}
```

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: That's not what I want. I know about resolve on routes, but I would like to resolve on a component which is not linked to a route, but a selector.

Comment: In that case ngOnInit like al37350 said it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must implements ngOnInit of OnInit interface to resolve data before rendering.
[In the Lifecycle hooks of angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), NGOnInit: Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties. Called once, after the first ngOnChanges.

Comment: It's not what I want but it will have to suffice. Rendering of page will not hold until completion of ngOnInit.